# selecting random data from a predefined list

Tags: sql-server, select, random

I have a list of employee ids, lets say:

```
Q1654
F2597
Y9405
B6735
D8732
C4893
I9732
L1060
H6720
```

These values are not in any one of my tables, but I want to create a function that will take in no parameters and return a random value from this list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without getting into random number theory, here's one method:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/192f2/1/0

it basically uses the function newID to generate a random value then sorts by it returning the top 1 record.

Given that it needs to be in a function and function's can't use newID... interjecting a view in the middle eliminates the problem.

```
Select * into myRand FROM (
SELECT 'Q1654' as val UNION
SELECT 'F2597'UNION
SELECT 'Y9405'UNION
SELECT 'B6735'UNION
SELECT 'D8732'UNION
SELECT 'C4893'UNION
SELECT 'I9732'UNION
SELECT 'L1060'UNION
SELECT 'H6720') b;


Create View vMyRand as 
Select top 1 val from myRand order by NewID();

CREATE FUNCTION GetMyRand ()
RETURNS varchar(5)

--WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
Declare @RetValue varchar(5)
--@configVar =
Select @RetValue = val from vmyRand
RETURN(@retValue)
END;
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I create this as a function? I want to return the value, but I keep getting `RETURN statements in scalar valued functions must include an argument.` when I try to return a varchar.

Comment: @user1911612 I've updated the solution to include a new fiddle as well and actually built the function to return a random value.  I had to gothough a view though to resolve an issue with the use of NEWID in a scalar function.

Comment: Yep, I ended up doing that, was just being stubborn when I posted my comment haha. Thanks a lot for the answer. I completely forgot about views!